# the name does not exist in the current context model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model

I'm creating the web using MVC structure. Besides, I had jquery to support on it. I have an issue make me stress whole day.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$("#addmore").click(function () {
            var i ; //get current step showing (+1) due to lenght start from 0
            for (i = $(".table .header").length + 1; i < @Model.StepCount; i++) {


                var rows = "<tr class='header'> "
                    + "<td class='prtoducttd'>" + @Model.TimeStamp[i] +  "</td>"

                    + "</tr>";
                $('#myTable tbody').append(rows);
            }
        });
```

it returns the error the name does not exist in the current context with i at TimeStamp. I don't know why. my TimeStamp is an array. If I put @Model.StepCount instead then the code run without error. but that is not what I want.

Please help me on this. If I can not pass the i value to model.TimeStamp then is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Is it jquery function?

Comment: not really. at that time @Model.TimeStamp had all value already. The script just append more rows to the table.

Comment: if its jquery then I think you should change @Model.TimeStamp[i] to @(Model.TimeStamp 
 + "[i]")

Comment: You are using the client side "i" as server side variable, which you cannot. So you may have to convert Model.TimeStamp to a client side object for the loop.